# DOM Error with javascript appending

Tags: javascript, dom

Using this code

```
var html='<div class="somediv"></div>';
var target=document.getElementById('contentArea');
target.appendChild(html);
```

I'm getting

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: That doesn't sound that exciting. Try: `null.appendChild("foo")`, note the error message, and work backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In doing DOM operations, before you get a hold of an element, make sure those elements are loaded already. putting the script to the bottom, just before the `</body>` tag should do

```
//all other HTML up here

    <script>
        var html=document.createElement('div');
        html.className = 'somediv';
        var target=document.getElementById('contentArea');
        target.appendChild(html);
    </script>

</body>
```

or you can run scripts using [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)

> The `load` event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
window.onload = function() {  
    var html=document.createElement('div');
    html.className = 'somediv';
    var target=document.getElementById('contentArea');
    target.appendChild(html); 
}
```

Comment: Now I'm not getting the null error, just `Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8`

Comment: Hey, can you finally tell me a jQuery prepend() alternative for javascript?

Comment: you can use [firstChild](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/firstChild) to reference the first child and then use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore) to insert before it

Answer (score 3):

Can't say for sure since you didn't provide the DOM from which you're selecting, but I'd guess that you're running your script before the `contentArea` element exists.

If so, place your script at the end of the `body` element.

```
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contentArea">
       ...
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // your script here
    </script>
</body>
```

Alternatively, just wrap everything inside:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // your script here
}
```

---

Not directly related, but you shouldn't be passing an HTML string to `appendChild`. You should create a DOM node, and append that.

```
var target=document.getElementById('contentArea');
target.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).className = 'somediv';
```

Answer (score 1):

`var target=document.getElementById('contentArea');` was not able to find the element with ID `contentArea`. Can you post the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error `Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8` trying to prepend an array of jQuery objects to a DOM Element. I found out that the spec allows you to prepend an array of DOM elements but not an array of jQuery objects.

Read this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11231 for details